# How to attach cables to ceiling using curved nails or hooks

Tags: ceiling, nails

I wanted to use [this trunking](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004GLCLK6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for the cables (power + hdmi) coming out of my ceiling mounted projector. But I'm renting and the ceiling is covered with... wallpaper. So I'm afraid of damaging the wallpaper the day I move.

I'm thinking about a safer solution: some sort of hooks or curved nails supporting the cables, located every 20cm or so along a line from my projector. Are there any kind of nails that could do the trick?

Comment: How are you mounting the projector, then? The answer may be that you can't ceiling-mount until you're in something you own and/or can alter more safely. (Outside of that, if the cables are light I'd be include to try cable-tie points attached with 3M "command" tape, which comes off cleanly... but I'd still worry about pulling the wallpaper right off the ceiling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trunking is fairly rigid and can be put in most locations without gluing it to the wall or wallpaper.  It merely serves to cover and contain the wires which are already safely covered.

You could cut the trunking to fit the run you want, enclose the wires and then use simple wire loops around the trunking in two or three places, held close to the wall with a screw and a plastic anchor.

You probably can find white coated wire to match the trunking.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of something around the trunking at 2 or 3 places. But it's not for the wall, it's for the middle of the ceiling. And I don't see where to put the screw and how to connect the screw to the wire loop! Would the screw sit between trunking and ceiling?

Comment: You could put the anchor and screw in the ceiling, wrap the middle of the wire around the screw head before final tightening, then bring the ends around the trunking and twist on the front. This would raise it slightly from the ceiling. Or put an anchor and screw on either side of the trunking and cinch the ends of the wires around the screw heads for a flusher look (but the screw heads will show).